# How can I search two pieces of strings in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get `"ID":`s and `"children":`, I kind of can now because lots of people from StackOverflow helped me, thank you, but now I'd like to search for IDs and children in that sequence. For now I can only get `"ID":`s or `"children":`s not both, how can I do it, any help is appreciated?

**What I'm getting**:

> 1,3,2

**What I'd like to get**

> 1,children,3,2

**My code is right below:**

```js
var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child1","id":2}]}]';
var arrays = [];
var t1 = data.match(/"id":[0-9]+(,|})*/g);
//arrays = t1;
for (var x = 0; x < t1.length; x++) {
  arrays.push(t1[x].match(/\d+/));

}
//var t2=data.match(/"children":/g);
alert(arrays /*+"\n\n\n\n\n"+t2*/ );
```

"Live long and prosper"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't transform that string in an object??

Comment: @Vanojx1 will it be easier to search?

Comment: for sure!! use $.grep then

Comment: @Vanojx1 thanks, I'll take a look at it right now

Comment: @Vanojx1 but I need to `alert` it, plus it needs to be `string` for an older language to process it, but thanks anyway

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay I'll

Comment: Then you can create a json using JSON.stringify and you have the string again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is parsing your string to a JSON: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child1","id":2}]}' );

console.log( obj.id );
console.log( obj.children[0].id );
console.log( obj.children[1].id );
```

Comment: That's amazing, now I'm gonna make a 'for' or 'while' to get all of them on the big one, Thanks for helping me :)